# How to make Barley bread?

Tags: baking, bread, barley

I started experimenting with baking using mixture of wheat and barley. The loaf was very tasty when made this way.

1. Barley is one of the grains that has gluten. So is there a recipe for bread with only barley?
2. In my experiment, I added 2/3<sup>rd</sup> wheat and 1/3<sup>rd</sup> barley flour. What is the maximum amount I can substitute, if pure barley bread can't be made?

I want the bread to raise nicely and have normal texture.

Comment: Barley has a lower gluten content than wheat, so using it for bread might be tricky.

Comment: The bread I made was very good. @Ron

Comment: So, did you experiment? How did it turn out?

Comment: @Ecnerwal It turned out ok. I used full wheat flour of unspecified gluten content (In my country gluten content is not mentioned in ready made whole wheat flour) and basket flour. The problem was that the bread breaks easily and the flavor was a little less intense!

Answer (score 2):

**Experiment more.** I'm not a slavish recipe-follower, and while I have the occasional brick when I screw up badly, I have yet to make actually inedible bread in several decades of playing fast and loose with bread recipes. Loaves that were not what I wanted, which I avoided repeating, yes. So bad it went in the garbage rather than be eaten, no.

I would suggest staying a bit on the wet side to give the lower gluten the best odds.

Perhaps try 1/3 wheat, 2/3 barley and see how you like it. If that doesn't work for you, then 100% barley probably won't either. If it does, 100% might. Only costs a couple of loaves to make the experiments. If the 1/3 wheat does not work to your satisfaction, try half wheat next. Do report back.